# Get day of week when using DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker, dayofweek

I'm working on a kind of tricky app where the day of the week is important.

To avoid to much hassle, here is my main problem:

I have a `DatePickerDialog` where the user selects a date. I want to know what day of the week this date is.

I'm thinking this should be easy, but somehow I can't figure it out.

I've tried a few things like using: 
`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` - I can only get it to return todays day
`Date.parse("1.16.2012").toString("dddd")` - Didn't get this to work at all

I really don't want to create a whole new calendar just for this simple problem.

Anyone good ideas guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very quickly, the date picker gives you year, month and day:

dayOfWeek = DateFormat.format("EE", new Date(year, month, day)).toString();

Iron the bugs I probably left yourself, sorry =)

Best regards.